# Find the solution of the equation given below :

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation : $6y^2dx -x(2x^3+y)dy=0$

My approach : first of all i applied methods of solving a ODE. That is variable separation, linear, homogeneous, using differentials, by substitution. Okay so its clear that variables cannot be separated. Now coming to linear, as it is its not in the correct form so i passed on to homogeneous. All terms are not of same deg so i was left with differentials and substitution. As it is i wasn't able to figure out the differential so the only method (i thought) was left was by using substitution and reducing it to any general form. Sadly I cannot even figure out what to substitute. I tried by hit & trial like by substituting $x/y$ or $xy$ as some terms had these expressions but it didn't work. Where did i go wrong? Hints please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply with $x^2$ and substitute $u=x^3$ to get
$$
2y^2\,du-u(2u+y)dy=0
$$
Now this looks homogeneous, as the coefficients are of degree 2, so set $u=vy$, $du=ydv+vdy$,
$$
2(ydv+vdy)-v(2v+1)dy=0
$$
which now is separable,
$$
\frac{2\,dv}{v(2v+3)}=\frac{dy}{y}.
$$

Comment: How did u think about this. I wanna know the thought process pls

Comment: In principle exactly the same way you tried, only generalizing the idea of a homogeneous approach to a substitution $y^a=x^bv$ for suitably chosen $a,b$. From the second term one is led to try $a=1,b=3$ or $a=-1, b=-3$, and it works, the second slightly more readable than the first..

Comment: Oh, i havent been taught this. What is this called?

Comment: There will be a - b/w the terms :)